# How to get width and height of attributes of svg from xml?

Tags: php, xml, svg

I have a svg image file and convert xml to get attributes of width and height but i am not getting the exact width and height of the image.

Original width and height 82*90 px

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [width] => 0.908528in
            [height] => 0.999992in
            [version] => 1.0
            [style] => shape-rendering:geometric
```

AFter converted svg showing as

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" width="100px" height="0px" version="1.0" viewBox="0 0 998 1099">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">

    .fil0 {fill:black;fill-rule:nonzero}

  </style>
 </defs>
 <g id="Layer_x0020_1">
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
  <path class="fil0" d="M801 0c97,28 145,67 145,118l-9 22 4 0 57 52c-16,50 -36,75 -61,75 -29,0 -69,-9 -118,-26 -21,46 -31,84 -31,114 17,84 26,151 26,201l0 57c0,12 38,62 114,149 23,21 35,40 35,57 0,12 -13,34 -39,65 -11,30 -24,55 -40,75 0,9 -7,16 -21,22l-5 -5 0 -4 5 -5c-21,0 -31,-23 -31,-70 41,-44 61,-71 61,-78l-171 -145c-16,-29 -26,-44 -30,-44 -19,0 -32,38 -40,114l-8 158c0,61 17,106 52,135 18,15 26,28 26,40 -6,9 -29,14 -70,17 -28,0 -44,-35 -48,-105 -3,-17 -10,-26 -22,-26l0 -4 9 -49c-12,-115 -25,-196 -39,-240l4 -18 -153 -26c-47,9 -70,31 -70,65 -5,43 -29,83 -70,119 -59,38 -88,73 -88,105 0,47 19,88 57,122l0 5c-3,11 -17,17 -39,17l-9 0c-32,0 -48,-13 -48,-39l-9 -193c-55,50 -83,86 -83,110l0 48c0,15 14,49 44,101l-40 13 -4 -5 -4 0 -18 5 -22 -26 0 -18 4 -171 -4 -39c50,-41 74,-82 74,-123l0 -70c0,-48 19,-96 57,-144l0 -5c-46,0 -75,-33 -87,-100l0 -35c7,-33 16,-49 26,-49l9 9 -13 53 0 9c8,55 32,83 70,83 19,-12 70,-24 153,-36l236 -113c60,-31 106,-89 136,-175 39,-97 75,-145 110,-145l30 -4z" fill="#000000"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, that I really got what you want to archive, but a svg is a "Scalable Vector Graphic" (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics), which means you can give that image any width or height you wish....

Comment: @oliver why i am getting it in inches format that is  [width] => 0.908528in

Comment: I really don't know, perhaps the src you've got the xml sends this attributes. But in fact, you can ignore this, because you an svg could have any dimensions.